# Externalize / reuse Helm _helpers

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have several apps of different shapes and purposes, each with their own `templates/` folder as generated by `helm create chart`.  The templates within each App are sufficiently different to justify having them as one-offs.  However, the `_helpers.tpl` is identical for all of them.  I'd like to externalize/reuse this `_helpers.tpl` template so that I don't need a copy of it in every app.

What I have currently looks something like this:

```
App1
|--app (random source code crap, irrelevant)
|--chart
|---templates
|------_helpers.tpl
|------ deployment.yaml
|------ other unique templates

App2
|--app (random source code crap, irrelevant)
|--chart
|---templates
|------_helpers.tpl
|------ deployment.yaml
|------ other unique templates
```

I'd like to centralize this `_helpers.tpl` so that I don't need to maintain N versions of it.  I'm imagining something like this, but I'm open to whatever:

```
Common
|--chart
|----templates
|------ _helpers.tpl (I live here now and was removed from the 2 Apps below)

App1
|-- app (random source code crap, irrelevant)
|-- chart
|--- templates
|------ deployment.yaml
|------ other unique templates

App2
|-- app (random source code crap, irrelevant)
|-- chart
|--- templates
|------ deployment.yaml
|------ other unique templates
```

I have tried doing this with a symlink pointing `AppN/chart/templates/_helper.tpl` to `Common/chart/templates/_helper.tpl` but that's clearly bad and I imagine there's a built-in way to do this that I'm just not finding.

Even if `AppN/chart/templates/_helpers.tpl` needs to exist only to read `../../_helpers.tpl`, that's good enough but I'm not sure how to approach that given the YAML-y/Go-y syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up solving this by inverting my file structure into something like:

```
Parent App
|--Chart.yaml // new
|--values.yaml // new
|--templates // new
|----_helpers.tpl // automagically gets referenced in charts/*/templates
|--apps (source code stuff, irrelevant)
|--charts
|----App1
|------Chart.yaml
|------values.yaml
|------templates
|--------deployment.yaml (and others)
|----App2
|------Chart.yaml
|------values.yaml
|------templates
|--------deployment.yaml (and others)
```

Which follows the "subchart" pattern outlined here more closely:  https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/

Even though these are independent charts, not dependencies on some parent chart like this structure would indicate, this is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

If one Helm chart includes another as a subchart, any `{{ define }}` templates anywhere in any of the parent or child charts are visible to all of the charts to be `{{ include }}`d or `{{ template }}`d.  This means that you can create a [library chart](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/) that only contains the helpers, with basically exactly the structure you show above

```
common
+-- Chart.yaml
\-- templates/
  +-- _a_helper.tpl
  \-- _another.tpl
```

This looks like a normal Helm chart in that it has a `Chart.yaml` file and a `templates` subdirectory, but inside `templates` are only `_*.tpl` files and not `*.yaml` files, and those files only contain `{{ define }}` top-level directives.

In your application charts, you can consume the library chart like any other chart dependency.  If these are all checked into the same repository, you can use relative `file:` URLs to point at the common chart.

```yaml
# app1/Chart.yaml
dependencies:
  - name: common
    repository: file://../common/
```

You do need to remember to run `helm dep up` before deploying the application chart; this makes a copy in the `charts` subdirectory.

(If you're using modern Helm 3, you can flag the library chart with `type: library` in the `Chart.yaml` file.  If you're using obsolete Helm 2, the dependency needs to go in a separate `requirements.yaml` file.  You can't usefully configure the library chart with values; if an application chart calls `{{ include "common.some.template" . }}` it will pass along the parent chart's view of `.Values` as part of the template parameter.)

Comment: Interesting.  So if my Deployments all differ from each other only by a variable Ive extracted to Values, can they extend this template such that I'd have only one deployment.yaml to maintain, total, instead of 1 per?

Comment: If you have a `{{ define }}` template that produces the Deployment spec, that can work.  If you have common Kubernetes objects that you always want to produce, you can also use a normal chart as a dependency (don't include the `type: library` marker, do include `*.yaml` files, you need a specific values layout to configure the subchart).